# Hide content on tablet and mobile and removig it from DOM

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and ould like to hide content from tablet and mobile devices but not by css (display:none) but rather removing it from the DOM so that it isn't loaded in first place. What would be the best way? I tried

```
function not_mobile_shortcode($atts, $content = '') {
  if (wp_is_mobile() === true) {
$content = '';
}
return $content;
}
add_shortcode('not_mobile', 'not_mobile_shortcode');
```

and then used the shortcode, but that doesn't seem to be that reliable(and it doesn't work when developing and user dev tools).

Comment: As the webserver might not really know whether the request comes from a tablet or mobile phone, this might work better in the browser